# Cannot read property 'result' of undefined infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, infinite-scroll

Got my infinite scroll working with some odd behavior.  I keep getting an TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined.

My data is retrieved but keeps fetching more data resulting in blank lines of html in my table and I'm not sure of what is going on.

In the code below i've tried result.data | data  and then vm.items[i]

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
    vm.items = [];
    vm.busy = false;
    vm.loadMore = function () {
        if (vm.busy) return;
        vm.busy = true;
        productDataService.getProductList()
            .then(function (result) {                   
                console.log(result.data);
                vm.items = result.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
                    vm.items.push(vm.items[i].result);                        
                    vm.busy = true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.items = [];
    vm.busy = false;
    vm.loadMore = function () {
        if (vm.busy) return;
        vm.busy = true;
        productDataService.getProductList()
            .then(function (result) {                   
                console.log(result.data);
                for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    vm.items.push(result.data[i].result);                        

                }
                vm.busy = false;
            });
```

Comment: this duplicated the the result.  The original result was 77 with this logic now 154 and still has the extra table lines in the html

Comment: I've edited the answer, the logic is that new items should be append to vm.items array. and I don't know how the service "getProductList" knows to paginate the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect this block:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
       vm.items.push(vm.items[i].result);                        
       vm.busy = true;
}
```

Each time this for loop iterates, you are adding an element to `vm.items`, making `vm.items.length` = `vm.items.length + 1`, which you are using as the condition in your for loop: **`i < vm.items.length`**. This loop is chasing its own tail, i.e. you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

remove the line *vm.items = result.data;* and iterate over *result.data* instead